# Link Table - Displaying the Correct Info

Tags: c#, html, sql, entity-framework

I was hoping someone could help me. I am using MVC5 to build a project, essentially it allows people to sign up for a football match. Here's a rough guide to my data model using EF 6:

Player:
ID
Firstname
Lastname
Email
Phone

Match:
MatchID
Location
DateTime
Cost
MaxPlayers

Matchday:
MatchdayID
MatchID (FK)
PlayerID (FK)
Paid

I have my views to list all the players, and to show matches, however when I add a player to a match (in the matchday table) this creates a new row in the Matchday table, which is fine.

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is:

In my Match view I want to be able to click View, this will then load the instance of matchday and load the players signed up for the particular game.

I hope that makes sense, any help is greatly received.\

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you have a specific problem that you are running into?  If so, please update your question with your relevant programming code so that we can better help you.

Comment: *What have you tried?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question :)
but you probably want something like this

```
class Player
{
    public virtual IList<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}

class Match
{
    public virtual IList<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

And Entity config

```
HasMany(match => match.Players).WithMany(player => player.Matches).Map(x => x.ToTable("Matchday").MapLeftKey("MatchID").MapRightKey("PlayerID");));
```